# Are there any performance/functionality differences between installing the New Relic RPM as a gem vs. as a Heroku add-on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, newrelic

I am hosting my Rails 3 application on Heroku and would like to add New Relic monitoring.

I notice that Heroku has an add-on that I suppose sets everything up for you, but I also notice that it doesn't create a "real" New Relic account - instead, it creates a Heroku-specific New Relic account that you can only access through Heroku.

What I am curious about is: are there any differences in ...

1. **Functionality**

   Mainly, does the Heroku-specific add-on offer any additional Heroku-specific features other than configuring the service for you? It seems to me that, if not, it might be better to use the gem so as to avoid any mysterious Heroku monkey-patching?
2. **Configurability**

   Does only being able to access the New Relic account via Heroku have any downsides (other than the annoying Heroku header frame taking up the top of every screen)?
3. **Performance**

   Does the Heroku set-up afford any performance benefits over self-installation of the gem?
4. **Cost**

   It looks like the Heroku New Relic add-on charges by the dyno. Does this make it more or less expensive overall than a comparable plan directly through New Relic? If it's more expensive, does it have any features that justify the extra cost other than the simplified configuration?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Functionality**

AFAIK it does not add any functionality besides adjusting and viewing through Heroku.

**Configurability**

This is the biggest upside. Heroku is all about making things easier and with the plugin all you have to do is install it you are ready to go.

**Performance**

Heroku plugins are essentially heroku-gems that get pulled in somewhere along the line. We would need to research how the plugin was made; obviously if the plugin used something faster than ruby then it would probably be faster than the new-relic gem which is just made of ruby.

**Cost**

I do not think you are missing anything here. You will end up paying two parties, so whatever Heroku charges that is your extra cost being $0.06 dyno.